# Justification of assumption of constancy of Spring Constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

In experimental analysis of Newton's 2nd law usually a spring is stretched to some length $l$, connected with a mass and then acceleration is measured.One does the same thing for some other mass. Then it is argued that since spring is stretched to equal distances, force produced by it must be same. Thus one shows that
$$\frac{m_1}{m_2}=\frac{a_2}{a_1}$$
However, I am not able to understand that how can we simply assume that equal lengths means equal forces? Afterall we can't rule out the possibility that the mass attached to the spring changes this force, or more appropriately that the spring force is given by
$$F=-K(m)l$$
Where $K(m)$ is a function of mass attached to the spring whose acceleration is to be measured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the spring constant $k$ measures the stiffness of the spring. It depends on the material from which the spring is made, the thickness of the spring, and other factors. Therefore, it has nothing to do with the mass of the attached object; so, $k$ cannot be a function of the mass of the attached object.

Second, Hooke's law explains a restoring force that a spring exerts on whatever object is attached. It has nothing to do with the object attached. It is a property of the spring and differs from one spring to another. Experimental evidence also showed that the restoring force is mass-independent and only depends on the displacement from the equilibrium position and the stiffness $k$ of the spring.

Hope that helps!